# Multi-Row Autosize Scrollable FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I have 50 images. I need to add these images in `FlowLayoutPanel`, 30 images for 1st row after that wrap row and 20 images in second row. So I also need to show scrollbars on control.

I am dividing video into frames(images) and shown in `FlowLayoutPanel`. When I upload first video below are the code to set image :

```
for (i = 1; i < len - 1; i++)
{
    ImagePanel mybt = new ImagePanel(storagePath + words[0] + "_" + 
                                     i + ".jpg", words[0] + "_" + i + ".jpg");
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(mybt);
}
```

After that when I upload second image I want to show images like in first row we have first video images after break I need to show second video upload images.
If anybody knows how it can possible.

Comment: @RezaAghaei like I have 50 images in ImagePanel I need to add these images in flowlayooutpanel 30 images for 1st row after that wrap row and 20 images in second row.

Comment: You can use SetFlowBreak:

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have used this but no success could you please refer me demo link so I can review the demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the result like you see in screenshot:

- Put your `FlowLayoutPanel` in a `Panel` with `AutoScroll` property set to `true`
- Set `AutoSize` property of your `FlowLayoutPanel` to `true`
- Set `WrapContent` property of your `FlowLayoutPanel` to `true` (Default)
- Set `AutoScroll` property of your `FlowLayoutPanel` to `false` (Default)
- When adding controls you can use [`SetFlowBreak`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.setflowbreak(v=vs.110).aspx) to break the flow of controls for those one you need.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var btn = new Button() { Text = i.ToString() };
        if (i == 5 || i==15 )
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.SetFlowBreak(btn, true);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

Here I am breaking the flow, at 5 and 15.

Comment: Its not breaking the flow I forget to telling you that my flowLayoutPanel have autoscroll property false and wrap content false

Comment: @vishuminhas No problem, check the update; use a panel that its autoscroll property is set to true and your flowlayoutpanel autosize to true, (wrapcoontent = true and autoscroll=false default values)

Comment: Thanks man do you know  now how we can add Hscroll and Vscroll for this?

Comment: @vishuminhas You are welcome :)  since the `Panel` that hosts your `FlowLayoutPanel` is auto size, then the scrollbars will be shown automatically when needed.