# Docking a Control inside a Docked FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, layout, controls

We added the property "Dock = Dockstyle.Fill" to our FlowLayoutPanel so that it resizes and fills its parent control. Now we added two GroupBoxes to the FlowLayoutPanel. These should have the same width as the Panel, but when we use "Dock = Dockstyle.Top" it doesn't work.

Problem is, we tried to set the width with "Width = Parent.Width". That would work but with our approach, to create the UI via a XML File, at the moment we want to set the width, the GroupBoxes doesn't have a parent yet. It will be added to the FlowLayoutPanel later.

By the way we also added the "FlowDirection = TopDown" to the FlowLayoutPanel, but if the GroupBoxes become smaller it places them side by side instead of TopDown.

So we are looking for a way to get all controls beneath each other and to get all GroupBoxes the same width as the FlowLayoutPanel.

Thanks for every help,

Dominic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case that you described, when you only want top-down flow, you can simply use Panel instead of FlowLayoutPanel. Set the panel `AutoScroll` to true, and its `Dock` to `Fill` and then add group boxes to panel and set `Dock` property of them to `Top`.

**Note:**
For future uses of `FlowLayoutPanel` you may find this helpful:

> [How to: Anchor and Dock Child Controls in a FlowLayoutPanel
>   Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171633(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> This is the general rule for anchoring and docking in the FlowLayoutPanel control:
>
> For vertical flow directions, the FlowLayoutPanel control calculates
>   the width of an implied column from the widest child control in the
>   column. All other controls in this column with Anchor or Dock
>   properties are aligned or stretched to fit this implied column. The
>   behavior works in a similar way for horizontal flow directions. The
>   FlowLayoutPanel control calculates the height of an implied row from
>   the tallest child control in the row, and all docked or anchored child
>   controls in this row are aligned or sized to fit the implied row.

**Example:**

For example following, if you run following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var control = new GroupBox()
    {
        Text = i.ToString(),
        Dock = DockStyle.Top,
        Height = 40
    };

    this.panel1.Controls.Add(control);
    //To reverse the order, uncomment following line
    //control.BringToFront();
}
```

The result will be:

```
4
3
2 
1
0
```

You can reverse the order of items, by uncommenting the comment code.

Comment: Thanks for your replay Reza. I'm going to try it later this day ;)

Comment: Hey, I just tried your solution with a small test XML File. It should work like this. The only problem is that the last control with DockStyle.Top is at the beginning. So for example when I create GroupBox1 with Top and afterwards I create another GroupBox2 with Top, then the GroupBox2 is on Top of GroupBox1. But the order of the controls should be GB1 and below that GB2

Comment: @Dyrdek You can see the example code I added to the answer.

Comment: @Dyrdek Let me know if you find the answer helpful:)

Comment: Ok :)   At the moment I stil  got the problem with the wrong order. We are reading from a XML file and add the controls from there. So GroupBox1 is added before GroupBox2. :/ Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @Dyrdek Did you check the edit? `control.BringToFront();`. The sample code is working properly. maybe you have a tiny mistake in your codes. Changing the order is too easy, event you can add your controls in reverse order.

Comment: Your code works fine (Thanks for that ;) ) The problem I got now is, that our program is reading an XML file and creates a UI depending on the XML. But it is reading from the top to bottom. So it is creating the GroupBox1 and brings it to the front. After that it creates a second GB and set that to the front, so it is above the GB1 in the Panel :/    Problem is, we should do `.BringToFront` at the end, but at the moment that's not possible with the XML reader.

Comment: @Dyrdek Very easy to overcome! I don't have your code, but you can add normally or you can add and then bring to front / or send to back, you also can use `this.Controls.SetChildIndex(yourGroupBox, 0);` to put it at top.

Comment: I'm working on it. :) Great Thanks so far! I'll report if something new comes up :)

Comment: @Dyrdek I will wonder if none of options could can solve your problem. While I think the answer is the best solution for such problem.  Also you may want to check these my accepted answer [Reordering controls in a regular panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888790/reordering-controls-in-a-regular-panel) and [Manage FlowLayoutPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564463/manage-flowlayoutpanel)

Comment: I now solved the problem by using a TableLayoutPanel :) For every control added I add a new row to the panel and fill in the control into it. By default the border of the TLP is not visible (perfect). So everything is right structured and in the correct order.      Thanks for your help Reza ;)

Comment: @Dyrdek By the way, when you find an answer helpful, you can kindly mark it as accepted by click on check mark near the answer, and/or vote it up by click on arrow near the answer, this way it will be more useful for other users.

Comment: @Dyrdek Maybe the answers posted need some change to apply in your case, but they will be useful for other users too:)

Comment: @Dyrdek Thank you, feel free to leave a message for me if you need some more help:)

Comment: @RezaAghaei - This is a helpful answer. However, in my case, it is not guaranteed the `Panel` contains only docked `GrouoBox`es. I also have other controls which should not take the width of the `Panel`, and **must** be rendered upside down so I am obliged to use a `FlowLayoutPanel`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Sipo Instead of stacked group boxes in above example, use stacked panel controls hosting other control.