# Reordering controls in a regular panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, panel

ContolPanel is type: FlowLayoutPanel
sender is a panel that i have a click on.

How do i reorder the order my Usercontrols is set in my FlowLayoutPanel?

This is how i add my Objekts(UserControls) to my FlowLayoutPanel

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        var panel = sender as Panel;
        switch (panel.Name)
        {

            case "TypePanel":
                ContolPanel.Controls.Add(new Type().Initialize(_ConnectionStr, _connection, _brugerLNr, _klinikLNr, _speciale, _ICPC, _segmenterStrings).SetModifiedCallBack(FilterModified));
                break;
        }
    }
```

I add this like 4-5 times and have alot of diffrent once, this this is just one.
What is the best method to reorder thies with a "+" and "-" button?

I thouth of saveing all the controls in a `List<Controls>` And then reorder them with something like

```
ControlList[1] = ControlList[2]
```

and then inset all the controls from the list into the FlowLayoutPanel.
But this just  dosnt seem to work out for me. Is there a easy way of doing this smart?

[image]

Comment: -Do you have any screenshot? -How do you add your user controls to container panel? -What kind of reordering do you need?  It's better to edit your question and ask a more clear question.

Comment: Here is a screenshot http://prntscr.com/8mje3f Its all in danish, but as you can see i want to be able to reorder the red boxes. with some arrows or a + or -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your user controls to a panel and set `Dock` property of your user controls to `DockStyle.Top`, then as a good idea change [z-order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984382(v=vs.71).aspx) of user control using [`Parent.SetChildIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex(v=vs.110).aspx) to move it up or down.

To do so, add these two methods to your user controls:

```
public void MoveUp()
{
    if (this.Parent == null)
        return;

    var index = this.Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(this);
    if (index <= this.Parent.Controls.Count)
        this.Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(this, index + 1);
}

public void MoveDown()
{
    if (this.Parent == null)
        return;

    var index = this.Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(this);
    if (index > 0)
        this.Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(this, index - 1);
}
```

Also you can support move up using <kbd>+</kbd> and moving down using <kbd>-</kbd> keys, by overriding `ProcessCmdKey` in your user control:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Add:
            this.MoveUp();
            break;
        case Keys.Subtract:
            this.MoveDown();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

And also you can add a move up `Button` and a move down `Button` in your user control and handle `Click` event of those buttons in your user control:

```
private void MoveUpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MoveUp();
}

private void MoveDownButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MoveDown();
}
```

Since we created `MoveUp` and `MoveDown` public, You can move a user control up and down in form:

```
myUserControl1.MoveUp();
```