# Can't get custom user control to autosize to width of a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, autosize, flowlayoutpanel

I have made a `UserControl` that consists of a `SplitContainer` with each panels of the split having some text that can be set upon initializing.

In the main application, I have a `FlowLayoutPanel` that loops through a list and news up these `UserControl`s (1 for each item in said list) and adds them to the `FlowLayoutPanel`.

All this seems to work, except the `UserControl`s refuse to resize to fill the width of the `FlowLayoutPanel`.  I've tried many combinations of setting Docks/Anchors/ect, but nothing seems to work.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious... the closest I got was setting the `FlowLayoutPanel` to `Autosize=true`, `Dock=Fill`, `AutoScroll=true`, and the `UserControl`s `AutoSize=true`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, you do, if the control is always supposed to fill the width then there's no point in flowing anything.  Just use a regular panel.

Comment: ... And set `Dock` property of `UserControl` instances to `Top`, Also set `AutoScroll` property of `Panel` to true. For example take a look at this similar [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32887572/3110834).

Comment: @HansPassant I used Flow because I am adding many items and it made it much easier for that, when I use `Panel`, only the first `UserControl` shows up so I'm assuming I'd have to manually arrange them?

Comment: @HansPassant Nevermind, your advice + Reza Aghaei's link got me sorted.  Thanks!