# Adding a usercontrol next/under existing one

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a button which when pressed adds a UserControl into a panel.
Essentially what i want is the next time you press it, it would add another exact same userControl but underneath the last one.

So far i have tried this:

```
  int count = 0;
  private void B_AddQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        QuestionAdder QA = new QuestionAdder();
        i++;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            Panel.Controls.Add(QA);
            GBX_Title.Text = i.ToString(); //This was to test to see if its counting
        }
    }
```

essentially this is working but what i think is happening is that it's adding user controls on top of each other. I tried changing the top and left but to no avail.

Maybe if I check if there is a user control, then add the next one below it?

<s>**EDIT:**  I did test flowLayoutPanels but I can't use this, since I would be having more userControls which must go NextTo the last userControl</s>

**EDIT:** My Mistake, you can very well do this by using flowLayoutPanel, setting flowDirection to TopDown and disabeling wrap contents, thanks!

Comment: Set the location for the new QA object to be below any previous one; or use a flowlayout panel bur Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix  I did test flowLayoutPanels but I can't use this, since I would be having more userControls which must go NextTo the last userControl

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: When you want only top-down flow, you can simply use `Panel` instead of `FlowLayoutPanel`. To do so, set `AutoScroll` property of the `Panel` to true, then add user control instances to the panel and set `Dock` property of them to `Top`. Take a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32887572/3110834).

Comment: @Flame - I am not sure I understand what do you mean. Can you please explain more specifically why couldn't you use a `FlowLayoutPanel`?

Comment: I do not understand this: "since I would be having more userControls which must go NextTo the last userControl"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a regular `Panel`, you could use a `FlowLayoutPanel` and set its `FlowDirection` property to `TopDown`.