# Make FlowLayoutPanel.AutoSize to work with fixed rows or columns

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I am creating a left right slider control, by placing a FlowLayoutPanel inside a Panel and set the FlowLayoutPanel.Autosize to true.  The Panel size is fixed, these are some properties i set for the FlowLayoutPanel.

```
FlowDirection = LeftToRight
AutoSize = true
AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink
WrapContents = true
```

At runtime i programatically add buttons to the FlowLayoutPanel which can look like this

[image]

The problem is that i wanted to achieve multiple rows by setting a fixed amount of row or columns, but it is always in a single row. That is if i choose say 3 rows, all the buttons will flow in 3 rows only with as many columns as possible or vise versa

```
pnlSlider.SetFlowBreak(btn,true)
```

This is what i want to achieve

[image]

- The black box is the panel
- The brown box the FlowLayoutPanel inside the Panel
- The green box are the buttons added at runtime

Is there any solution for this

**EDIT**

I was refered to a solution here [Multi-Row Autosize Scrollable FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564463/multi-row-autosize-scrollable-flowlayoutpanel) which seems to relate to what I need, but this solution is setting FlowBreaks in designtime, and the amount of rows cannot be fixed.

A sample of what i was trying to replicate. if you look closely, these are buttons place in a panel, most probably a flowlayout sliding inside another control

[image: sliding panel]

Comment: Take a look at this post [Multi-Row Autosize Scrollable FlowLayoutPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564463/multi-row-autosize-scrollable-flowlayoutpanel). It seems it's exactly what you need.

Comment: Its looks similar, i edited the title a little, but its not really what I am looking for

Comment: DId you see this `if (i == 5 || i==15 )`, he is breaking at each of these controls before adding, in this case the number of columns is fixed to 5, which is not what i need, instead fixed rows is what I am looking for

Comment: can the flowbreak be set at runtime, mine does not work

Comment: Btw, the linked post is not setting breaks at design-time. I set breaks in run-time. Also I can set the row numbers to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an auto-size, scrollable multi-line `FlowLayoutPanel`, you can host the `FlowLayoutPanel` in an auto-scroll panel. Also the `FlowLayoutPanel` should be auto-size:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Size = New Size(320, 160)
    Dim p = New Panel() With {.AutoScroll = True, .Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
    Dim f = New FlowLayoutPanel() With {.AutoSize = True, .WrapContents = True}
    p.Controls.Add(f)
    Me.Controls.Add(p)
    For i = 1 To 20
        Dim btn = New Button() With {.Text = i.ToString()}
        If (i Mod 10 = 5) Then f.SetFlowBreak(btn, True)
        f.Controls.Add(btn)
    Next
    Me.ActiveControl = f.Controls(0)
End Sub
```

In above example, I inserted a break on 5th and 15th item to make the result multi-row. Also as you can see, the horizontal scrollbar is visible:

[image]

Comment: you are adding the flowbreak before adding the control to the flowpanel, i set flowbreak after adding the buttons sometime later, but it doesn't work

Comment: I couldn't understand what is not working :) The code I posed is a simple example that shows how to add break. I've no Idea about what you tested but you can use the code in the sample. Also if you share a simple example which reproduce the problem (an example like I shared) I'll take a look at it and will try to help you :)

Comment: how did you make this gif?

Comment: I used [ScreenToGif](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/). This tool allows you to record a selected area of your screen and save it as a Gif.

Comment: your answer actually didnt solve my problem, i will send a gif of what i am looking for

Comment: No problem :) I'll take a look at your edit if you notify me. But the sample works properly, maybe it's not what you are looking for. Anyway, I believe it's useful :)

Comment: And what's the difference with the image in answer? I couldn't get :)

Comment: the difference is you are setting flow breaks manually before adding the buttons, this becomes useful when the ui is resized. I tried to set flowbreaks after adding the buttons, but it doesnt break as expected

Comment: Sorry but I could't get what you mean by *You are setting flow breaks manually before adding the buttons*. I set break for each button which I add. What's the desired behavior? I can simply show 31 buttons in 2 rows which the first row contains 18 items and the second one contains 13 items. Is this what you are looking for?  If this is not, so explain what's the expected behavior of control. I can't see any difference between these 2 gifs, except than those left and right buttons which is out of scope of this question.

Comment: I'm really curious to know what stop you from applying the solution. If I can I'll solve it :)