# C# - Automatically add 'X' amount of buttons, one after another.

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows form where I am adding a button control for each monitor attached to a computer. Naturally as the number of displays very from PC to PC, I want to automatically add a button per display and add them so they are displayed in a row.

Currently my code is as so:

```
 foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
                {

                    Button monitor = new Button
                    {
                        Name = "Monitor" + screen,
                        AutoSize = true,
                        Size = new Size(100, 60),
                        Location = new Point(12, 70),
                        ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                        Image = Properties.Resources.display_enabled,
                        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                        Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold),
                        ForeColor = Color.White,
                        BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                        Text = screen.Bounds.Width + "x" + screen.Bounds.Height
                    };


                    monitorPanel.Controls.Add(monitor);

                }
```

This is working however, it's simply placing each button on top of each other where there is more than one display (as I expected it would):

[image: Currently.]

What I want to achieve is that each button is added, but in a row next to each other. I've tried various threads, searches on Google etc to no avail. Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

[image: What I'm trying to achieve.]

Comment: You should use the [Toolstrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) control to do this; it's easy to add and remove buttons to it at runtime, and it takes care of all of the positioning.

Comment: Why do you want to set location manually? You can simply use a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` without need to calculate `Location` of buttons. For example take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564463/multi-row-autosize-scrollable-flowlayoutpanel) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426888/dynamic-button-creation-placing-them-in-a-predefined-order-using-c-sharp) or many other samples about using those controls to create dynamic flow/table of controls.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't need to really, it's just I'm not overly experienced in coding and still learning a lot as I go. I roughly knew how to do it the way I have done, but I'll check out the recommended resources. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIRC `AllScreens` can be indexed, so:

```
var padding = 5;
var buttonSize = new Size(100, 60);
for (int i = 0; i < Screen.AllScreens.Length; i++)
{
    var screen = Screen.AllScreens[i];
    Button monitor = new Button
    {
        Name = "Monitor" + screen,
        AutoSize = true,
        Size = buttonSize,
        Location = new Point(12 + i * (buttonSize.Width + padding), 70),
        ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
        Image = Properties.Resources.display_enabled,
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
        Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold),
        ForeColor = Color.White,
        BackColor = Color.Transparent,
        Text = screen.Bounds.Width + "x" + screen.Bounds.Height
    };

    monitorPanel.Controls.Add(monitor);
}
```

That ought to do it.

Advantages of this over the other answers: counter/indexer is built into the loop.

Comment: Perfect, this worked a treat. The buttons overlap ever so slightly, but I'm sure I can play around and fix this. Many thanks! :)

Comment: @Rawns No problem mate, glad it's solved. Just mess with `padding` and find a value that makes it look the way you want. :)

Comment: Good job, but consider these points: *1)* If you use `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` you don't need to set `Location` of controls manually and can control layout in a table or in vertical/horizontal flow simply. *2)* Why you set Size if you set `AutoSize=true`? You don't need to use both options. *3)* You should not concatenate a string and an integer, like you did in `"Monitor" + screen` or `screen.Bounds.Width + "x" + screen.Bounds.Height`. You can use `string.Format` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't try but shouldn't you set the Location different per button?

```
Location = new Point(12, 70),
```

to e.g.

```
Location = new Point(12 + (100 + gap) * screen_index, 70),
```

where 100 is the width of the screen
gap is the gap between two screens
and screen_index the index from left to right

Answer (score 3):

You are in control of setting the position. You are actually setting it yourself:

```
Size = new Size(100, 60),
Location = new Point(12, 70)
```

I'd suggest you increase location with the size of each button, and additional padding:

```
Location = new Point(screenNumber * (100 + 5), 70)
```

Or something. Of course `screenNumber` is a counter you have to declare, initialize and increment upon each iteration.

Comment: Order-of-operations shows that your padding here is not going to take effect. Imagine a few loops of this: first loop: `0 * 100 + 5 == 5`, second loop: `1 * 100 + 5 == 105`, third loop: `2 * 100 + 5 == 205`, perhaps you meant `screenNumber * (100 + 5)`?