# Set button fill all the width & top of parent in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, tablelayoutpanel

I want to create a form with columns of buttons. The buttons should fit all the width of form. Also I want to push it to top of form as possible.  It should look like this:

```
|----------------------------------|
|           Form caption           |
|----------------------------------|
||--------------------------------||
||Button0                         ||
||--------------------------------||
||--------------------------------||
||Button1                         ||
||--------------------------------||
||--------------------------------||
||Button2                         ||
||--------------------------------||
|                                  |
|                                  |
|           free space             |
|                                  |
|----------------------------------|
```

Usually I work with C++/Qt and it's rich of layouts. As I understand c# is not so good in that. I've found that `TableLayoutPanel` with 1 column can do that. The only thing I want is to push all the buttons to top.
So I've created the following code:

```
// panelButton was created by VS with following params:
this.panelButton = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
this.panelButton.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.panelButton.Name = "panelButton";
this.panelButton.RowCount = 1;


for(int i = 0;i < 3;i ++)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    button.Height = 40;
    button.Text = "Button" + i;
    button.Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs args) {});
    panelButton.Controls.Add(button, 0, i);
}
```

But the layout I get is wrong - `button0` and `button1` are 40px height as expected but `button2` fills all the space when I expect it will be 40px.

ADDED: I've found a workaround. I add

```
panelButton.Controls.Add(new Control(), 0, rowIndex);
```

after the loop and so thet works as expected.

Comment: Set `button.Dock` to `System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top`

Comment: By the way, layout is not related to `C#` it's the job of UI frameworks like `Windows Forms` and `WPF` which both work well.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, than also doesn't work. All the buttons are 40px height but the layout 's height doesn't grow. If height of all buttons > height of panel it add scrollbars

Comment: If you want panel grows instead of showing scrollbars, set its AutoSize to true.

Comment: Ok, the trick with `AutoSize = true` + `panelButton.Dock = DockStyle.Top` works as expected. Thanks! Can you add your comment as answer?

Comment: The only thing that not good is that it doesn't add scrollbars

Comment: See the answer, it describes about autoscroll and autosize.

Comment: To see an example about when `TableLayoutPanel` is useful take a look at this post: [Dynamic button creation & placing them in a predefined order using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968993)

Comment: To see a `FlowLayoutPanel` example take a look at this post: [Multi-Row Autosize Scrollable FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564463)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `TableLayoutPanel` for such task. It's enough to use a `Panel` and add buttons to it. For each button you need to set its `Dock` to `Top`.

If you want the panel grows instead of showing scrolls, you can set the panel `AutoSize=true` and `AutoScroll=false`.

If you want scrollbars, just set it's `AutoSize=false` and `AutoScroll=true`.

**Example 1**

An auto sized form containing a panel which has a list of buttons:[(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd6ZD.png)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Controls.Clear();
    this.AutoSize = true;
    this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    var panel = new Panel();
    panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panel.AutoScroll = false;
    panel.AutoSize = true;
    panel.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    this.Controls.Add(panel);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var buttun = new Button();
        buttun.Text = string.Format("Button {0}", i + 1);
        buttun.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        panel.Controls.Add(buttun);
    }
}
```

**Example 2**

A form containing an auto-scroll panel which has a list of buttons:[(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awCAg.png)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Controls.Clear();
    this.AutoSize = false;
    var panel = new Panel();
    panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panel.AutoScroll = true;
    this.Controls.Add(panel);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var buttun = new Button();
        buttun.Text = string.Format("Button {0}", i + 1);
        buttun.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        panel.Controls.Add(buttun);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Layout is not related to `C#` it's the job of UI frameworks like Windows Forms. To learn more about layout in windows forms take a look at these documents:

- [Windows Forms Layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951306.aspx)
- [Layout in Windows Forms Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229674(v=vs.110).aspx)